# CMake or Waf for D project

Tags: build-process, build-automation, cmake, d, waf

We are looking for adequate build tool for a desktop GUI application to be written in D (using Qt toolkit), consisting of several native libraries, using 3rd party C-lib(s). It has to build on Linux (native development) and Mac as well on Windows. We might adopt [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) as IDE.

Waf already has support for D language, while CMake is just receiving it [cmaked2](http://code.google.com/p/cmaked2/).

CMake uses special language, while Waf is pure Python...Otoh, CMake, via CPack, can produce packages in several formats as well as GUI installer for e.g. Windoze.

Any pro/cons and what would you use?

We excluded Scons for speed reasons and autoconf, so, please, advice against CMake/waf only.

**Update:** Although not received any reply here, we were researching in other places, did some reading & testing and decided to use [Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) (1.6. release is just around the corner).

Answer (score 9):

Waf is very fast and has been chosen as the build system for Samba (http://samba.org/). It is also used by many proprietary projects because it lets you do crazy things that are impossible in Make/CMake.

Comment: What kinds of crazy things?  Good crazy, or bad kludgy crazy?

Comment: waf provides you with the power of python, docs are great, and a bunch of usecases exist for the common tasks (e.g. glib/gtk bindings and alike)
I'd go for it anytime, and it's lightning fast

Answer (score 5):

#### I would/do use CMake

I've seen CMake used in many more places than Waf.  Most importantly the KDE project is now using CMake.

I did some research on google code search:
there are [2,097 wscript](http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=&btnG=Search+Code&hl=en&as_package=&as_lang=&as_filename=wscript&as_class=&as_function=&as_license=&as_case=) files in various opensource projects
compared to [36,914 CMakeLists.txt](http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=&btnG=Search+Code&hl=en&as_package=&as_lang=&as_filename=CMakeLists.txt&as_class=&as_function=&as_license=&as_case=).

So CMake is definitely more popular.

I also tried to use google trends to see which was gaining more traction CMake or Waf.  I wasn't succesful as Waf is too general at term (ie ***W**ife **A**cceptance **F**actor*), and "Waf build" doesn't show up in google trends at all.

Scons is known to have terrible performance issues.  As Waf is a Scons derived I worry about its performance.

Lastly, CMake has terrible syntax and Waf has beautiful syntax.  Since you're going with D it looks like you're willing to go off the beaten path for superior tools.  In that case Waf may be the perfect fit.

Comment: As far as performance, have you seen this benchmark: http://tinyurl.com/9chgax ? Yes, I prefer nice tools and investing time in brushing my python skills instead of learning obscure scripting language.

Comment: Those benchmarks are really informative.  It makes we wish CMake had a bjam generator.

Comment: I've used waf for several projects, and in my experience it is very fast.

Comment: @gour CMake has a macro language not a scripting language.

Comment: @9emE0iL18gxCqLT "CMake has its own basic scripting language..." (http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax) ;)