# How to compile the c++ source files, generated in run-time, using waf?

Tags: c++, waf

I have protobuf proto-files in source tree. I want to generate the source files from proto-files on every change and on first run (e.g. I create new proto-file). Then, I want to compile shared library from these source files and preserve them in source tree.

What is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What project manager are you using?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: what is a "project manager"? - I use Eclipse IDE and waf build-system.

Comment: Oh, OK, I didn't know that waf is a build system.

Comment: use cmake instead ? It's a though choice, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895863/cmake-or-waf-for-d-project but at last, you would have more people to answer you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself:

```
from waflib import Build, Utils, TaskGen

def build(bld):
    bld.post_mode = Build.POST_LAZY

    # some bld(...) tasks that generate source files.

    bld.shlib(source='main.cc', dynamic_source='**/*.cc', target='test')

@TaskGen.feature('cxxshlib')
@TaskGen.before('process_source')
def dynamic_post(self):
    if not getattr(self, 'dynamic_source', None):
        return
    self.source = Utils.to_list(self.source)
    self.source.extend(self.path.get_bld().ant_glob(self.dynamic_source))
```